# PHP: preg_replace() dash expect {4} digits before any dash

Tags: php, regex, replace, preg-replace, str-replace

I am trying to replace any dash into my string except when there are four digits before the dash.

Situation: I got rewrited URL like

```
/Alfa-Romeo/147/2001-2005/1.9-JTD-100-PK
/Alfa-Romeo/147/2005-
```

The GET values I extually need is:

1. Alfa Romeo / Alfa Romeo
2. 147 / 174
3. 2001-2005 / 2005-
4. 1.9 JTD 100 PK / 1.9 JTD 100 PK

To pass trough my functions and filter the result. I tryed to:

```
$value = str_replace('-', ' ', $value);   
$value = preg_replace('/\d{4}/', '$0-', $value);
```

This is resulting into stripping every dash as I asked the code with my

```
str_replace('-', ' ', $value);
```

I was expecting that \d (Any digit) {4} (Exactly 4), $0- (Pasting dash after match) on the just stripped $value with str_replace dash for space would do the trick but it's not..

Step by step in my point of view a string like "2001-2005" would become (This is the point it's breaking since it's replacing the dash into a space properly)

- "2001 2005" (str_replace dash for space)
- "2001- 2005-" (preg_match 4 digits add dash)

As you can see since there is a double match as well as on "2001" and on "2005" it's placing a dash after it.

When I'm doing such a thing like

```
$value = str_replace(' ', '', $value);
```

After the first two replaces a string like "1.9 JTD 100 PK" would become 1.9JTD100PK and this is unwanted! Besides that I still got a unwanted dash after my "2005" in the last example. A string like "2005- " would be fixed with adding the third step.

Hope you guys are understanding the issue and can resolve this for me?

Comment: `$value = preg_replace('/\d{4} /', '$0-', $value);` - note space after {4}

Comment: @Lashane this is rewriting "2001-2005" > "2001 -2005" instead of " 2001- 2005-" and "2005-" > "2005 -" instead of "2005- " replacing the space with nothing would resolve this indead but when im putting "1.9 JTD 100 PK" into the function its giving "1.9JTD100PK" since the spaces are removed.

Comment: ups, you need `$value = preg_replace('/(\d{4}) /', '$1-', $value);`

Comment: This seems to work! What is the $1 doing diffrent that $0? and the round braces to capture everything together are doing some magic aswell?

Comment: The trick is that the group isn't capturing the trailing space.  You're only restoring the four digits now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use negative look behind to require that a dash isn't preceded by four digits.

```
$value = preg_replace('/(?<!\d{4})-/', '', $value);
```

`(?<! ... )` is a negative look behind group.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually do this without look behinds if you use something like:

```
$value = preg_replace('/((?:\d{4}-|[^-])*)-?/', "$1 ", $value);
```

You can see this working here: http://ideone.com/aKK3jD

Note that `preg_replace` will do a global replace. So you won't need to run this in a loop or anything.

Comment: What about "/Alfa-Romeo/Brera/07-2008-/1750-TB-200-PK" this is returning "1750-TB 200 PK" for the last parameter since there are four digits followed up by a dash. How to exlude if there are not nummeric character after that dash, dates are only fomatted like "07 2008-" or "07 2008-08 2015" or "07 2007-2008" so its not always four digits-four digits wich needs to be exluded.

Comment: @Jordy We're getting a little scope creep in the question huh? Handling the dates should probably be made into a new question. If you can write one up and post a link here I'll try to come answer it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29154025/php-preg-replace-dash-expect-for-dates

Comment: @Jordy Looks like you got an answer, did that one solve your problem?