# PHP: preg_replace() dash expect for dates

Tags: php, regex

Allright I got the following rewritted URL examaples:

```
/Alfa-Romeo/Brera/06-2006-07-2008/2.4-JTDM-200-PK
```

This is just the URL the be nice but to find my vehicles I need the following values wich correspondent to my database. Therefore I'm using this code.

```
$value = preg_replace('/(?<!\d{4})-/', ' ', $value);
```

It will return the following and behind the slash I will write down the expected value

1. Alfa Romeo / Alfa Romeo
2. Brera / Brera
3. 06 2006-07 2008 / 06 2006-07 2008
4. 2.4 JTDM 200 PK / 2.4 JTDM 200 PK

Im getting the right result, but when I go to the next example here is what's going wrong:

```
/Alfa-Romeo/Brera/07-2008-/1750-TB-200-PK
```

Returns / Expect

1. Alfa Romeo / Alfa Romeo
2. Brera / Brera
3. 07 2008- / 07 2008-
4. **1750-TB 200 PK** / 1750 TB 200 PK

The result is logic since my preg_replace is replacing any dash with a space expect when there are four digits followed up by a dash. But in this case I dont want the dash behind the "1750" see bold above, aswell.

So I need to extend this preg_replace that it will only keep the dashes for a date format. Some of the date formats are:

1. 07 2005-08 2010
2. 2012-2015
3. 2012-
4. 07 2005-2010

As you can see sometimes after the dash there is nothing and sometimes there is just a year or a year and a month. How can I remove my dash behind the "1750" see bold above?

Comment: is the dash always followed by a letter in the case of `1750-TB` but not for the date formats?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

based on what you posted, maybe

```
(?<=\d{4})-(?=[a-zA-Z])|(?<!\d{4})-
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/235)